# Create multi-column table in SwiftUI using Table framework - iOS 16 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, swift-playground, ios16

I'm trying to follow Apple's [Table](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Table) tutorial to create a multi-column table.

Using the exact code from the tutorial in Xcode 14 beta 3 (iOS 16 beta) gives me the following result:

[image]

where the expected result based on the tutorial is

[image]

As you see, I can only see one column without header. Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Works fine on iPad, probably it decides there is not enough space on iPhone. Joke... looks like a bug.

Comment: Yeah look like a bug as @Asperi said, and good morning joke.

Comment: Thanks, Asperi, and tail.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, tables show only the first column. To show it as a multi-column, implement compact-specific logic. Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/Table

> **Using tables on different platforms**
> macOS and iPadOS support SwiftUI tables. On iOS, and in other situations with a compact horizontal size class, tables don’t show headers and collapse all columns after the first. If you present a table on iOS, you can customize the table’s appearance by implementing compact-specific logic in the first column.

Comment: And how to implement the compact-specific logic?

Comment: If you 'implement compact-specific logic', the SwiftUI framework will produce multiple columns w/ headers?  I tried using `.compact` (to produce a column w/ a two character name and one character content) - still a single column.  I used `.width (min:30, max:50)` - still a single column?  You have a micro-example of this?